# Picasso Set Background Image

Tags: android, picasso

So I've been trying to load a background image for my LinearLayout via Picasso for awhile. I've tried several different approaches but none of them seem to work.

Approach 1:

```
Picasso.with(LoginActivity.this).load(R.drawable.login_background).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                loginLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(LoginActivity.this.getResources(), bitmap));
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                // Implement Logic
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                // Implement Logic
            }
        });
```

I've also read that the Target may be garbage collected. Even after accounting for that through a custom layout, the background image was absent.

Approach 2:

```
final ImageView background = new ImageView(LoginActivity.this);
        Picasso.with(background.getContext())
                .load(R.drawable.login_background)
                .fit()
                .into(background, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        loginLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(background.getDrawable());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });*/
```

I have no idea as to why this doesn't work.

Approach 3:

```
BitmapDrawable loginBackground = (BitmapDrawable) LoginActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_background);
        int width = loginBackground.getBitmap().getWidth();
        int height = loginBackground.getBitmap().getHeight();
        ImageView background = new ImageView(LoginActivity.this);
        Picasso.with(background.getContext())
                .load(R.drawable.login_background)
                .resize(width, height)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(background);
        if (background.getDrawable() != null) System.out.println("BACKGROUND NOT NULL");
        loginLayout.setBackground(background.getDrawable());
```

I tried to create my own BitMapDrawable here and load the contents through Picasso. Finally, I set the background.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1 simple question. Why are you trying to load an image from your drawable with picasso?

Comment: Because otherwise several frames are being skipped if I directly set the background resource to the image. I heard Picasso can prevent that.

Comment: I hardly recommend you to read this [issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/263)